# How can I loop though the 3rd dictionary?

Tags: python

My question may be simple but how can I loop through the third dictionary in this list? I tried many things but I'm getting the three dictionaries:

```
red_infarto=[{"deportista":[True,False],
              "alimentación_equilibrada":[True,False],
              "hipertenso":[True,False],
              "fumador":[True,False],
              "infarto":[True,False]},
              
              {"deportista":[],
               "alimentación_equilibrada":[],
               "hipertenso":["deportista","alimentación_equilibrada"],
               "fumador":[],
               "infarto":["hipertenso","fumador"]},
               
               #this part i want loop 
               {"deportista":{():[0.1,0.9]},
                "alimentación_equilibrada":{():[0.4,0.6]},
                "hipertenso":{(True,True):[0.01,0.99],
                              (True,False):[0.25,0.75],
                              (False,True):[0.2,0.8],
                              (False,False):[0.7,0.3]},
                "fumador":{():[0.4,0.6]},
                "infarto":{(True,True):[0.8,0.2],
                           (True,False):[0.7,0.3],
                           (False,True):[0.6,0.4],
                       (False,False):[0.3,0.7]}}]
```

Comment: ``red_infarto[2]``

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "loop," do you want to hit each value or just iterate over the key value pairs?

Comment: I want to loop the key/values pairs

Comment: You access the third element of the list -- as shown in any tutorial on lists.  That gives you the dict you want.  Then you iterate through the dict, as shown in any tutorial on dictionaries.

Comment: I dont understand the negatives votes , we re just here to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the third dictionary in list:

```
print(red_infarto[2])
```

loop through it items:

```
for key,val in red_infarto[2].items():
    print(key)
    print(val)
```

Comment: ah! wasn't aware that there are time limits ^^